# GET request with multiple pages in Ionic 2

Tags: html, typescript, web, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I'm trying to send a GET request to an API server in my Ionic 2 app, the returned JSON is too huge to be in one page, so the server divides it into pages, each with a different URL (Obviously).

My problem is that I don't know how to call the other page in the same request, I heard that using Infinite Scroll will help, and I looked at the official docs, but I was still unable to solve my problem.

Here's my code for the **App.ts**:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
     NavParams,private http:Http) {

  this.http.get("http://linkofAPI")
    .subscribe(data => {
      // console.log(data['_body']);
      this.items = JSON.parse(data['_body']).data;//Bind data to items object
      console.log(this.items);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);// Error getting the data
    });
}
```

And my **App.html**

```
  <ion-item class="items" *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">

  <h3 dir="rtl">{{item.content.ar.title}}</h3>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call other page in the same request" ? Do you want to request 2 different URLS by making 1 single call to the server !!

Comment: @DeveshSati I want my function to call a get request to the next page once it finishes the current page, I heard it was possible using the ion-infinite-scroll, but I'm not sure on how to apply it.

Comment: Do you want to implement infinite scrolling or do you want to load the data from the 2 different requests and combine the server response into 1 ?

Comment: @DeveshSati The main priority is to retrieve the data from the 2 different requests (or however many pages the api request contains), and combining them into one response, using one function if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wont write the actual code here but give you the direction on how to achieve what you want.

Steps:

1) Declare a variable which you want to end up containing the result after combination of the two responses. I do not know the structure of returned data, but I am guessing it returns an array of some kind since pagination is involved. Let this variable have 0 elements initially.

2) Make the two requests independently in the same way as you have done. This ensures that the second call wont have to wait for the first one to finish, and they can work asynchronously.

3) When the GET calls return successfully, add the elements to the variable declared in first step. You can use 'concat' function to achieve this in a single statement if you wish.

That should be it.

If you want to make the first call, wait for it's response and then make the second call, I suggest you look into "Promise Chaining".